# ¿Cómo cambiar la ruta del cache generado?

Tags: php

El siguiente código me permite poder reproducir videos de manera remota, lo que hace es crear un cache de ese video, el mismo que se esta guardando en la carpeta principal del dominio: `example.com`.

Ahora el problema de ello es que estos caches pueden pesar igual o más que el video y, necesito poder borrarlos, pero con una tarea programada y, al hacerlo desde la carpeta principal del dominio: `example.com` me borrara la aplicación, entonces necesito poder cambiar la ruta para guardar ese cache por ejemplo `videoCache` que sería igual a: `example.com/videoCache/` y, así poder crear una tarea programada para eliminar toda esa información de esa carpeta. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar la ruta?

```
        $filePath = 'https://ia801407.us.archive.org/5/items/205_20210726/205.ia.mp4';
        function __construct($filePath) {
            if (substr($filePath, 0, 7) === 'http://' || substr($filePath, 0, 8) === 'https://') :
                
                $this->path = md5($filePath);
                
                // URL path did not exist in local server
                if (!file_exists($this->path)) :
                    $urlStream = fopen($filePath, 'r');
                    $dest = fopen($this->path, 'w');
                    
                    # stream_copy_to_stream
                    # https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php

                    stream_copy_to_stream($urlStream, $dest);
                    fclose($urlStream);
                    fclose($dest);
                endif;
            else :
                $this->path = $filePath;
            endif;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente tenes que agregar el directorio a la propiedad `$this->path`

#### Ejemplo:

```
// ... código anterior
$this->path = 'videoCache/' . md5($filePath);
// ... resto del código
```